# How to add extra modules to OpenCV4Android?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, cmake, android

I am now using NDK to implement the image processing method, and I want to import some extra modules, like xphoto and matlab, to OpenCV, so that I can include the extra libraries into my cpp file.

I have already downloaded the extra modules. Those modules look like this:

```
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── doc
├── LICENSE
├── modules
├── README.md
└── samples
```

and the `modules` folder looks like this:

```
modules
├── aruco
├── bgsegm
├── bioinspired
├── ccalib
├── cnn_3dobj
├── contrib_world
├── cvv
├── datasets
├── dnn
├── dnns_easily_fooled
├── dpm
├── face
├── freetype
├── fuzzy
├── hdf
├── line_descriptor
├── matlab
├── optflow
├── phase_unwrapping
├── plot
├── README.md
├── reg
├── rgbd
├── saliency
├── sfm
├── stereo
├── structured_light
├── surface_matching
├── text
├── tracking
├── xfeatures2d
├── ximgproc
├── xobjdetect
└── xphoto
```

Since I am not quite familiar to configuring the CMake settings, please give detailed steps.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that you could just add/include the contrib modules to the OpenCV4Android's pre-built libraries. I would say that you should compile OpenCV+contrib from source. To do so, you have two options:

Option 1: Following this [steps](https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/building-opencv-for-android-from-source/) you could compile OpenCV+contrib for a target ABI.

Option 2: You could use OpenCV's python cross-compilation script, which enables you to compile OpenCV+contrib for many available ABIS (armeabi-v7a,armeabi,arm64-v8a,x86_64,x86,mips64 and mips), doing the following steps.

-Download/clone OpenCV and the extra contrib modules source code.

-Then, you should run this command line to compile OpenCV for all mentioned ABIS adding Opencv contrib modules as input parameter of the pyhton script.

```
   python ../opencv/platforms/android/build_sdk.py  --extra_modules_path ../opencv_contrib/modules <dir-to-store-result> ../opencv
```

If you had not provided the paths to Android SDK and NDK, to your environment variables, so that your build system is aware of their location, you could also add them as input parameters to the python script.

```
python ../opencv/platforms/android/build_sdk.py  --extra_modules_path ../opencv_contrib/modules --ndk_path <your-path-to-ndk-top-level-folder> --sdk_path <your-path-to-sdk-top-level-folder> <dir-to-store-result> ../opencv
```

This way you would have a complete OpenCV+contrib modules compilation inside < dir-to-store-result >, with the same structure as the OpenCV4Android.